# How to retrieve data from a model type?

Tags: javascript, ember.js, reverse-engineering

I am a complete noob with Ember and I must retrieve data from an external website written in Ember.

I installed the Ember inspector plugin and I see the following:

[image]

**What javascript command can I input in the Console debugging window to retrieve the data (Id and Number) in the list?**

I cannot rely on Ember inspector for the data retrieval, the tool is only used to inspect the structure.

---

### Update 1

Thanks to @kumkanillam, I made it here:

[image]

It seems that I can know the name and type of each attribute of an item in my list, but I am not able to get its value.

The `happy` array is the result of this call from his example : `myStore.peekAll('common/following-info').toArray()`

Comment: Most of the Ember applications have rest endpoints. If this application has a similar architecture, you can inspect the endpoints via network tab. Then you can get the json objects.

Comment: Thanks, it helped me to debug my ember applciation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at this
https://guides.emberjs.com/v2.14.0/ember-inspector/container/
https://guides.emberjs.com/v2.14.0/ember-inspector/object-inspector/#toc_exposing-objects-to-the-console

It's explained very well images.

You can expose objects to the console by clicking on the `$E` button within the Inspector. This will set the global $E variable to the chosen object.

You can also expose properties to the console. When you hover over an object's properties, a `$E` button will appear next to every property. Click on it to expose the property's value to the console.

---

### Update 1

You can run the below code in console.

```
 function getApplication() {
  let namespaces = Ember.Namespace.NAMESPACES;
  let application;

  namespaces.forEach(namespace => {        
    if (namespace instanceof window.Ember.Application) {
      application = namespace;
      return false;
    }
  });
  return application;
}
```

you can use the above function to get application instance, from there you can lookup access `service:store`, from there you can use `peekAll` required model. to view all the required data alone, I used the JSON methods like stringify and then parse.

I actually used the LinkedIn site and used their model `common/following-info` for demoing. you can choose whichever model you want to view,

```
var myApp = getApplication();
var myStore = myApp.__container__.lookup('service:store')
myStore.peekAll('common/following-info')
myStore.peekAll('common/following-info').toArray()
JSON.stringify(myStore.peekAll('common/following-info').toArray())
JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(myStore.peekAll('common/following-info').toArray()))
```

---

Update 2

`myStore.peekAll('common/following-info')` Here it returns [DS.RecordArray](https://emberjs.com/api/ember-data/2.14.5/classes/DS.RecordArray) and it extends [Ember.ArrayProxy](https://emberjs.com/api/ember/2.14.1/classes/Ember.ArrayProxy), that means you can use methods available in ArrayProxy. [forEach](https://emberjs.com/api/ember/2.14/classes/Ember.ArrayProxy/methods/forEach?anchor=forEach) to iterate or to get specific index record use [objectAt(index)](https://emberjs.com/api/ember/2.14/classes/Ember.ArrayProxy/methods/objectAt?anchor=objectAt)

In your case, You need to know the property name of the model to get the values for specific property like

```
let allRecords = myStore.peekAll('common/following-info');
allRecords.forEach(function(item){
  console.log(item);
  console.log(' Using get method to value ', item.get('propName'));
});
```

to get specific index value,

```
let allRecords = myStore.peekAll('common/following-info');
let firstRecord = allRecords.objectAt(0);
console.log(' First record propName value is',firstRecord.get('propName'));
```

In your case, you want to print the entire object without giving each property names, then there is no inbuilt way, We need to do some hacking using `JSON.stringify` and `parse` to get the perfect object you are looking for. and then you can use `Object.values` to get all the values.

```
let arrayOfObjectWithOnlyKeysAndValuesOfModel = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(myStore.peekAll('common/following-info').toArray()));
arrayOfObjectWithOnlyKeysAndValuesOfModel.forEach(function(item){ 
 console.log('item',item);
 console.log(' item values alone ', Object.values(item));
});
```

Comment: Hi and thanks, this is helpful for debugging! I would require to extract the data without having to resort to Ember inspector though...is it possible?

Comment: for debugging purpose ah ? then you can expose `store` property to window like `window.EmberStore = this.get('store');` in application controler init method or wherever you want. and after that you can use `EmberStore.peekAll('list')`

Comment: I dont have access to the Ember code though...it is an external website to me and I try to scrape information from it

Comment: I don't know how to do that, You might need to go through Ember inspector code for that, that browser extension is doing that

Comment: @ibiza I updated my answer after referring ember-inspector code. please have a look at it

Comment: Thanks for your help, it works great! :) Just missing a small detail that I hope you can resolve with a one-liner (see my update 1)

Comment: Thanks, it helped me to debug my ember applciation